# Ionic Push Notification not displaying notifications on Notification bar

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am developing an hybrid app using `ionic` for this I have implemented the push notification I am able to get an push notification from ionic.io site, but issue is that while getting **push notification logo shows me white on the notification bar**.

```
android = new android
{
  image = strImage,
  icon = "",

  data = new data
    {
     priority = "1",
     visibility = "1",
     title = "PushTitle",
     message = "Test Message",
     style = "inbox",
     summaryText = "SummaryText",
     noteId = "1234567"                                
    }
  }
```

this is my code I don't understand whats goes wrong with it. notification on notification bar look like this **highlighted in red color**.

[image]

what I need to add into it so that is display the proper on notification bar.

Comment: when app is runing and then push came... does icon still looks the same?

Comment: @Kriti not push came after when app is not running, but on notification bar it displays white.

Comment: so just read doc about push icon from https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/  icon should have transparent background

Comment: @Kriti I have done changes as per the link. but I have 1 ques how to configure this image into my code so that it will render properly or not need to add any line of code just this image file will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just created transparent logo in www/resources folfer with .png file. and then run command from command prompt.

```
ionic resources --icon
```

this link will help you to understand about push icon [push icon](https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/)